# Routes in Rails3 - Controller and routes for 2 post functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to write an app in rails 3 and I'm having some trouble figuring out the routes and controllers for a test that I want the user to take. The basic requirements for this app are:

1. Users, Tests and Questions are all in separate models.
2. A User has_many Tests. A Test has_many Questions
3. Provide a link on the user_profile page to /test/new to create the test record.
4. Provide a link on /test/new to /test/:id/part1 (where :id is the test_id) so that the user can complete the first part of the test. Questions will be retrieved from the db and presented on this page.
5. Provide a link on /test/:id/part1 to /test/:id/part2 so that the user can complete the second part of the test. Again, questions are retrieved from the db.
6. Provide a link on /test/:id/part2 to submit the test and return to the user's profile.

I've completed the models, which even pass their tests, so I think I have finished parts 1 and 2.

user.rb

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests
end
```

test.rb

```
Class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions
end
```

question.rb

```
Class Question < ActiveRecrod::Base
  belongs_to :test
end
```

My issues start when I try to put these models together using routes and controllers.

routes.rb

```
resources :users

resources :tests do
  member do
    post 'part1'
    post 'part2'
  end
end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Start The Test", new_test_path %>
```

tests/new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Part 1", part1_test_path(@test) %>
```

tests_controler.rb

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @test = Test.new(current_user)
  end

  def part1
    # still just a stub
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error when I click on the link to take Part 1 of the test:

```
No route matches {:action=>"part1", :controller=>"tests", :id=>#<Test id: nil, taken_at: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining a member of the routes it's expecting an existent test, ie. one which is saved and has an id.

e.g.

```
part1_test_path = /test/123/part1
```

What you need is a collection route.

```
resources :tests do
  collection do
    post 'part1'
  end
  member do
    post 'part2'
  end
end
```

e.g.

```
part1_test_path = /test/part1
```

edit

Suggested solution:

```
resources :test, :path_names => { :new => 'part_1', :edit => 'part_2' } *1

def new 
  @test = Test.new

#new view
form_for @test do
  ...

def create
  @test = Test.new params[:test]
  if @test.save
    redirect_to edit_test_path @test

def edit
  @test = Test.find params[:id]

#edit view
form_for @test do

def update
  @test = Test.find params[:id]
  if @test.update_attributes params[:test]
    redirect_to test_path @test 


def show # test results
  @test = Test.find params[:id]
  if @test.incomplete *2
    redirect_to edit_test_path @test
```

*1 See [rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments). This will give you urls like this

test/part1
test/123/part2

You should put all of your validation in the model; your requirements of test data. Conditional validation will be required, depending on whether it's a new_record? or not ie if you're at part 1 or 2.

*2
add a method to your model which checks test completeness.

```
def incomplete
  self.some_test_field.blank?
```

Let me know if you don't understand anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark. But, wont's this solution give me different routes for part1 and part1 (i.e. part1_test_path = /test/part1 and part2_test_path = /test/123/part2)? I'd like to be consistent between these so that the codebase is more maintainable. Using your insight that member expects an existent test, I've decided to call the create controller on the /test/new page and then try to redirect to part1. Seems promising.

Comment: Personally I'd go with my approach but yours is equally as valid. You might want to check out these railscasts episodes on complex forms if you haven't already. http://railscasts.com/episodes/73 They're for rails 2 but apart from some small syntax valid for 3.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Is there something about your method that would be more in line with "THE RAILS WAY"? I'm new to rails and I want to follow the canonical style as much as possible because I'm planning on handing this app off to other developers so I'm trying to follow - and learn - the conventions as much as possible.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer with what I would recommend you do and what I believe would be more inline with convention. :)

Comment: Thanks for such a great example. My specific case is just a little bit different from this but I really like how you've kept everything in the expected new, create, edit, update, and show methods.